# Segmentation Fault Mystery: How an unsigend long variable can crash system?

Tags: c

I was working on a C program to convert any other number system to decimals, below is the code for my program that was causing the problem:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdbool.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

float other_to_decimal(char *n, unsigned int base)
{
    float out = 0;
    size_t point_idx = 0,len = strlen(n);

    // check if input is negative
    bool input_is_negative = (n[0] == '-') ? true : false;

    // find the index of '.'
    while (point_idx != len && n[point_idx] != '.')
        point_idx++;

    // check if fractional part exists or not
    bool frac_part_exists = (point_idx == len || point_idx == len - 1) ? false : true;

    // convert the integer part
    const size_t end = input_is_negative ? 1 : 0;
    int power = 0;
    for (int i = point_idx - 1; i >= end; i--, power++)
        out += n[i] <= '9' ? (n[i] - '0') * pow(base, power) : (n[i] - 'A' + 10) * pow(base, power);
    

    // convert the fractional part
    if(frac_part_exists)
    {
        power = -1;
        for (size_t i = point_idx + 1; i < len; i++,power--)
            out += n[i] <= '9' ? (n[i] - '0') * pow(base, power) : (n[i] - 'A' + 10) * pow(base, power);
    }

    out *= input_is_negative ? -1 : 1;

    return out;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    printf("%f\n", other_to_decimal("1101.01", 2)); // output should be 13.25

    return 0;
}
```

(by the way, I run it on a Linux computer, but I am not sure if the output will be same, if you want to run this on Linux then don't forget to put -lm flag for math functions.)

I tried to find the error so hard and after a lot of effort, printfs and running it dozens of times I finally found the problem-causing part.

It was the declaration of that 'end' variable in line number 23, the problem was `const size_t end` and the solution was `int end`, looks strange right? the fun part it is the variable that can only have either 1 or 0, both supported by unsigned long int, which is exactly what size_t is, and it is only involved in comparison, and still, it makes its way to system and crashed it.

**My question is why on earth that `const size_t end` managed to cause a segmentation fault?!**

Comment: The reason is that `size_t` is unsigned (because nothing can have a negative size). You run into a problem when `i` is negative and you do `i >= end`.

Comment: "I request the readers to try to find the problem before reading further as it will improve the reader's debugging skills:" — that part doesn't increase reader's desire to help, to put it mildly. It reads closer to "you have to" or "it will be useful to you" (which is mostly incorrect) rather than "I ask for help".

Comment: I'd enable all compiler warnings and hunt them down to avoid such errors. Comparing integers of different kind (signed/unsigned) may behave unexpectedly in C and C++: when comparing unsigned with signed, the latter is converted to unsigned, `-1` becoming something like 4 billion. So your `for` loop will spin indefinitely if `end == 0`.

Comment: Bonus points for managing to use `char *`, `char`, `unsigned int`, `float`, `double`, `size_t`, `bool` and `int` in a single function.

Comment: Regarding debuggins skills... You failed to run your program even once in a debugger. You should immediately see that the loop does not terminate when you reach 0. You also should get used to use a minimum of command line options. Mentioning `-lm` is a start but the more important are: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`. They will tell you `warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: ‘int’ and ‘size_t’ {aka ‘const long unsigned int’} [-Wsign-compare]` which also immediately tells you what is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted by others in the top comments, as you have it, comparing `i` and `end` is problematic:

> when comparing unsigned with signed, the latter is converted to unsigned, `-1` becoming something like 4 billion. So your `for` loop will spin indefinitely if `end == 0`. –
> yeputons

If you compile with extra warnings: `-Wall -Wextra`, then line 28 is *flagged* by the compiler:

```
comparison of integers of different signs: 'int' and
      'const size_t' (aka 'const unsigned long') [-Wsign-compare]
```

If you change:

```
const size_t end = input_is_negative ? 1 : 0;
```

Into:

```
const int end = input_is_negative ? 1 : 0;
```

then the program compiles without the warning.

And ... It runs to completion with the output:

```
13.250000
```

---

*Side note:*

1. Your first `for` loop uses `int i`.
2. But, your second `for` loop uses `size_t i`.
3. These should [probably] be consistent (one way or the other).